# cant open visual studio solution

Tags: visual-studio, project

A friend sent me his visual studio project that contains 2 files:

> naomi.sln
>   naomi.v12.suo

When I try to open the first file I get the error in visual studios:

```
One or more projects in the solution were not loaded correctly. Please see the Output Window for details.
```

How can I open the project?

Comment: Is that literally all you have, 2 files?  In which case, your friend appears to have forgotten to send you the actual project(s) that are supposed to be within the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't actually have the project (only the solution - *.sln* file). The project file should have *.vcproj* or *.vcxproj* extension. The *.suo* file contains some solution user data (as seen in [[MS.Docs]: Solution User Options (.Suo) File](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2015/extensibility/internals/solution-user-options-dot-suo-file)). 
Get the project file that the solution references, and you'll be able to open it.